# Modify JavaScript Object and use setRowsData to write to individual cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using `getRowsData` to retrieve the information, but I would like to modify the values stored within a JS object and then write that modified value back into the cell. I would like to use the normalized header variable that was created with `getRowsData` to write back into the cell. So if I retrive the info using

```
var thirdEmployee = employeeObjects[2];
var stringToDisplay = "The third column is: " + thirdEmployee.firstName + " " + thirdEmployee.lastName;
stringToDisplay += " (id #" + thirdEmployee.employeeId + ") working in the ";
stringToDisplay += thirdEmployee.department + " department and with phone number ";
stringToDisplay += thirdEmployee.phoneNumber;
ss.msgBox(stringToDisplay);
```

Then, for example, I would assign a new value to the Javascript object `thirdEmployee.phoneNumber;` and then have it written into the proper location in the range (i.e., active row, column # based on header).

```
thirdEmployee.phoneNumber = "123-555-5555";
thirdEmployee.phoneNumber.setNewValue();
  or
setNewValue.thirdEmployee.phoneNumber;
```

Basically, it would be a modified version of `setRowsData` but allow for modification of one object and then telling that object to be written into the spreadsheet based on the active row & column based on the header.

Anyone use or know how to do this?

Comment: Google Apps script will let you write to the active row/col. There should be a way to do this with GAS. Is the JavaScript client side?

Comment: Yes, I am simply running the functions using menus.

Comment: I see you are using the "Extending Google Sheets" tutorial. It has a section for "Writing Data" did you try it? It looks like it should do what you are asking. (tutorial https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#writing ) Have you a lot of data, so much that it makes it slow, as it does have optFirstDataRowIndex to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

The `setRowsData()` helper function from the [Writing Data from JavaScript Objects to a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#writing) tutorial already supports the ability to write a single object. To use it, though, you need to provide both of the optional parameters `optHeadersRange` and `optFirstDataRowIndex`.

If we assume that your headers are in row 1, here's how you could update `thirdEmployee`:

```
var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
var thirdEmployee = employeeObjects[2];
...
thirdEmployee.phoneNumber = "123-555-5555";

setRowsData(sheet, [thirdEmployee], headersRange, 3 );
```